# Gridgain apply grid cache store jdbc

Tags: jdbc, gridgain

Somebody help me!

Please give an example to apply grid cache.store.jdbc in Gridgain.

I was read something like this, but it so old.

https://github.com/ssudarsa/gridgain-Community-3.6.0c/blob/master/examples/config/spring-cache-store-jdbc.xml
https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPersonStore.java

I wana use this in Gridgain 6.5

Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

This example should work with GridGain 6.5.6:
https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPersonStore.java